# Sqlite command error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mobile, titanium

I am running sqlite command in the sqlite manager.My command is as follows

```
  CREATE TABLE Answers(Answer TEXT, Answer_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Quiz_ID NUMERIC)
```

and it is giving me the following error

```
   [ near "CREATE": syntax error ]
 Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Help me in solving this error

thanks in advance

Comment: I just copy-pasted your sql and ran it.  It worked. Maybe your table already exists?

Comment: No one quiz table is alread there but no Answers table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE` is a valid keyword and cannot result in a syntax error at the beginning of a command.
Therefore, this `CREATE` cannot be at the beginning of the command.

When executing multiple commands, you have to separate them with a semicolon:

```
CREATE TABLE SomethingElse(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY /* ... */ );
CREATE TABLE Answers(Answer TEXT /* ... */ );
```